# Wordpress Custom menu not screen in appearance

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

The custom menu is working, but wp-admin is not showing the option "menus" in Appearance. I've tried many options, but none have worked so far. The links of custom menu work.

```
function.php

function meus_menus() {   register_nav_menus(
 array(
   'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
   'categorias' => __( 'Categorias' )
 )   ); } 
 add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'meus_menus' );


header.php

            <?php
                wp_nav_menu(array(
                ‘menu’ => ‘primary’,
                ‘theme_location’ => ‘meus_menus’,
                ‘container’ => ‘div’,
                ‘container_class’ => ‘classe_do_container’,
                ‘container_id’ => ‘id_do_container’,
                ‘menu_class’ => ‘classe_do_menu’,
                ‘echo’ => true,
                ‘menu_id’ => ‘id_do_menu’,
                ‘before’ => ”,
                ‘after’ => ”,
                ‘link_before’ => ”,
                ‘link_after’ => ”,
                ‘depth’ => 0,
                ‘walker’ => ”,
                ));
            ?>
```

Comment: you need to change all the typographical quotes (‘ ’) to regular quotes (' ')

Comment: I made the changes but it still does not work

Comment: I change in function.php to:

add_theme_support('menus');
  register_nav_menus(
   array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'pesqueiraonline' ),
    'categoria'  => __( 'Categoria Menu', 'pesqueiraonline' ),
   )
  );

And in header.php I add:
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You are hooking the wrong event. Try and change your `add_action()` so that it is triggered on the **init** event, instead.

```
add_action( 'init', 'meus_menus' );
```